# How to convert zfs /boot to ext4

Tags: zfs

I want to change /boot from zfs to ext4.
I've tarred the contents of /boot for safe-keeping.
I can't unmount /boot while linux is running because the kernel is in /boot.
If I use the LiveCD, I can get access to the disk containing /boot.
If I delete the boot partition, re-format as ext4, and un-tar into the new ext4 partition, what will happen when I reboot? Will zfs die because /boot is no longer zfs? Is there a safer way to delete /boot before reformatting that partition?
Is there a way to mount the zfs root partition while running LiveCD so I can access boot.tgz?

Comment: Theoretically, there's nothing wrong with your plan. But that's not a guarantee it will work. Evaluate and manage your risks: Be prepared to handle the most likely and most serious problems that you might encounter. Once your surgery is complete, write it up as an answer.

Comment: Do you have questions related to Ubuntu? ...because it is AskUbuntu, after all.

Comment: Sorry if I posted to the wrong group. I'm trying to get my upgrade of Ubuntu 23.04 (from 22.10) to work. It seems to be hung up on zfs, and I've been stuck in recovery-console hell for a week.